# Extract Multiple Values from string regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, extract

I have the string:

```
"BSSID:00:00:00:00:00:00<br>Encryption: WPA+PSK WPA+AES-CCM<br>Channel: 11<br><br>Current Clients: <br><br><br>"
```

I cannot figure out how to use regex to filter out the value of "BSSID", "encryption" and so on. 
I have tried this regex: `\b(BSSID:|Encryption: |Channel: )\b`
However, this does not work as thought. If someone could head me to the right direction, that would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex with `String.replace` function:

```
var str = "BSSID:00:00:00:00:00:00<br>Encryption: WPA+PSK WPA+AES-CCM<br>Channel: 11<br><br>Current Clients: <br><br><br>",
    replaced = str.replace(/\b(BSSID|Encryption|Channel)\s?:/g, "");

console.log(replaced);  // 00:00:00:00:00:00<br> WPA+PSK WPA+AES-CCM<br> 11<br><br>Current Clients: <br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```js
var input = "BSSID:00:00:00:00:00:00<br>Encryption: WPA+PSK WPA+AES-CCM<br>Channel: 11<br><br>Current Clients: <br><br><br>";
var items = input.split("<br>").filter( function(item){ return item.indexOf( ":" ) != -1 });

//console.log(items);

var map = {};
items.forEach( function( item ){
  var key = item.substring( 0, item.indexOf( ":") );
  var value = item.substring( item.indexOf( ":") + 1);
  map[ key ] = value;
})

//console.log( map );

console.log( map.BSSID ); //value of BSSID
console.log( map.Encryption ); //value of Encryption
```

Comment: Thank you, both your scripts works but i figured @RomanPerekhrest did a  cleaner approach. However, I ended up combining your suggestions to create the expected end result. Thank you alot!